# how to return dictionary value with api.onchange

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10, postgresql-9.5

I wanna return BoM materials in hpp_line table with @api.onchange,
unfortunately I get some error.. here's my code on paket.py file

```
from odoo import models, fields, api
class Paket(models.Model):
   _name = 'paket.perjalanan'
.....
equipment_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Package')
hpp_line = fields.One2many('hpp.line', 'paket_id', string='HPP Line', readonly=True)
.....
@api.onchange('equipment_id','hpp_line')
def _select_bom_list(self):
    for x in self.equipment_id.product_tmpl_id.bom_ids.bom_line_ids:
        subtotal = x.product_qty * x.product_id.product_tmpl_id.list_price          

        return {
            'value' : {
                'hpp_line' : {                      
                    # 'paket_id' : self.hpp_line.id,
                    'product_id' : x.product_id.id,
                    'product_qty' : x.product_qty,
                    'product_uom_id' : x.product_uom_id.name,
                    'unit_price' : x.product_id.product_tmpl_id.list_price,
                    'subtotal' : subtotal
                }
            }
        }
```

and here's my hpp_line.py file

```
class HppLine(models.Model):
   _name = 'hpp.line'

   paket_id = fields.Many2one('paket.perjalanan')
   product_id = fields.Char(string='Produk')
   product_qty = fields.Integer(string='QTY', readonly=True)
   product_uom_id = fields.Char(string='UoM')
   unit_price = fields.Integer(string='Unit Price', readonly=True)
   subtotal = fields.Integer(string='Sub Total', readonly=True, store=True)
```

also here is my xml code

```
               <page string="HPP Lines">
                <field name='hpp_line'>
                  <tree>
                    <field name='product_id'/>
                    <field name='product_qty'/>
                    <!-- <field name='product_uom_id'/> -->
                    <field name='unit_price'/>
                    <field name='subtotal'/>
                  </tree>
                </field>
              </page>
```

so here's the condition, when I change equipment_id, hpp_lines automatically return it's bom_line_ids in mrp.bom.line

but I get error message like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo.10/odoo/http.py", line 642, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo.10/odoo/http.py", line 684, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo.10/odoo/http.py", line 334, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo.10/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo.10/odoo/http.py", line 327, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo.10/odoo/http.py", line 942, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo.10/odoo/http.py", line 507, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/addons/travel/web/controllers/main.py", line 895, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/addons/travel/web/controllers/main.py", line 887, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo.10/odoo/api.py", line 689, in call_kw
    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo.10/odoo/api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo.10/odoo/models.py", line 5522, in onchange
    record._onchange_eval(name, field_onchange[name], result)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo.10/odoo/models.py", line 5421, in _onchange_eval
    process(method_res)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo.10/odoo/models.py", line 5400, in process
    self.update({key: val for key, val in res['value'].iteritems() if key in self._fields})
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo.10/odoo/models.py", line 5042, in update
    record[name] = value
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo.10/odoo/models.py", line 5245, in __setitem__
    return self._fields[key].__set__(self, value)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo.10/odoo/fields.py", line 933, in __set__
    value = self.convert_to_cache(value, record)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/odoo.10/odoo/fields.py", line 2064, in convert_to_cache
    raise ValueError("Wrong value for %s: %s" % (self, value))
ValueError: Wrong value for paket.perjalanan.hpp_line: {'product_uom_id': u'kg', 'subtotal': 100.0, 'product_id': 38, 'unit_price': 100.0, 'product_qty': 1.0}
```

Comment: Why not `self.hpp_line=...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that hpp_line is a o2m field so you need to write values in the ORM write format for o2m and m2m commands actions.

If you wanna to add a new line you could do it like:

```
@api.onchange('equipment_id','hpp_line')
def _select_bom_list(self):
    hpp_value = []
    for x in self.equipment_id.product_tmpl_id.bom_ids.bom_line_ids:
        hpp_value.append(
            (0, 0, {
                'product_id': x.product_id.id,
                'product_qty': x.product_qty,
                'product_uom_id': x.product_uom_id.name,
                'unit_price': x.product_id.product_tmpl_id.list_price,
                'subtotal': x.product_qty * x.product_id.product_tmpl_id.list_price
            })
        )

    return {
        'value' : {
            'hpp_line': hpp_value
        }
    }
```

Comment: yeahh it works.. but I have more than one records I want to view in hpp_line.. I guess the keyword is append.. but I still strugling to solve this..

Comment: just put all the `(0, 0, {})` values inside the list for hpp_line. Also you could build the list inside the for and assign it to the return dict

Comment: I tried to make a print for debuging first.. it works return this result`{'value': {'hpp_line': [[(0, 0, {'subtotal': 1.0, 'product_id': 51, 'unit_price': 1.0, 'product_qty': 1.0})], [(0, 0, {'subtotal': 1.0, 'product_id': 52, 'unit_price': 1.0, 'product_qty': 1.0})], [(0, 0, {'subtotal': 1.0, 'product_id': 53, 'unit_price': 1.0, 'product_qty': 1.0})]]}}`, but nothing's show when I try to return that thing..

Comment: Thank you.. finally it works... Why I didn't think about prepare an empty list before loop...

Answer (score 0):

```
@api.onchange('equipment_id')
def _bom_selection(self):
    value = {
        'value' : {
            'hpp_line' : []
        }       
    }
    for x in self.equipment_id.product_tmpl_id.bom_ids.bom_line_ids:
        subtotal = x.product_qty * x.product_id.product_tmpl_id.list_price  
        listing = [
            (0,0,{
                'product_id' : x.product_id.id,
                'product_qty' : x.product_qty,
                'unit_price' : x.product_id.product_tmpl_id.list_price,
                'subtotal' : subtotal
            })                      
        ]

        value['value'].setdefault('hpp_line').append(listing)

    return value
```

I try a different way because I didn't get idea how to loop the list effectively

Comment: I cannot do more, that will not work. Your code will generate [[(0,0,{})], [(0,0,{})]]. That's wrong see how to do it properly here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53151435/4451876. it will generate [(0,0,{}), (0,0,{})]